# Presenting UIViewController causes strange behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

When presenting a UIViewController using

```
[myUINavigationController presentViewController: paypalViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The new controller displays fine, but when it is dismissed the navigation breaks in the whole app. Pushing screens after this point using 'pushViewController' seems to push the view because I can 'click' buttons on the screen, but the UI itself does not update.

The strange thing is, that **presenting the view as above does work from certain screens but not others**. I have tried setting the UINavigationController on the screens that don't work to a *strong* variable, but that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have to call it on navigationController, can you call on some viewcontroller which is on screen.

Comment: The UINavigationController is passed through to a utility method and the presenting of the view is done inside that method. I could possibly try passing the view controller itself to that method?